# how to calculate time complexity for generators

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, big-o, generator

I have solved a problem with sliding window technique. As far as I understood, the time complexity should be O(N^2) since I used generators/yields in sliding_windows function and they will not be executed until being called in a loop. But, The platform which I am working on calculated the time complexity as O(N^3) and evaluate my code as very in efficient.

I am confused a bit. I have two question. First; Is the time complexity of the following code really O(N^3). Second; If my assumption is correct and the time complexity is O(N^2), is it still very inefficient?

thanks a lot in advance!

```
def sliding_windows(iterable, size=3):
    it = iter(iterable)
    windows = []
    for item in range(0, size):
        windows.append(next(it))
    yield windows
    for item in it:
        windows = windows[1:] + [item]
        yield windows

def solution(A):    
    min_average = (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]) / 3
    print(min_average)
    index = 0
    for window_size in range(3, len(A)):
        generator = sliding_windows(A, window_size)
        window_index = 0
        for window in generator:
            average = sum(window) / window_size

            if (average < min_average):
                min_average = average
                index = window_index
            window_index = window_index + 1

    return index
```

Comment: I think you are seeing your O(N^3) because in your first function you are first appending windows before yielding it. So this is a true for loop. You are then calling that function inside a for loop in the second function. If the value from the first function truly was yielded I think O(N^2) would be where you are at.

Comment: I changed the code, I used slicing and get rid of the first for loop. But the evaluation did not changed. its still O(N^3)

Comment: That is good as it points out that the reason is most likely within the second function. O(N^2) means the function will be directly proportional to the size of the input dataset, so your function appears to be (worst-case) faulty for big datasets. Perhaps it would decrease the time complexity if you split your second function into 2 functions. The first could yield the generator and the second could return the index.

Comment: I think you could then get the time complexity for functions 1 and 2 on their own, as your first function could be O(N), and your (new) second function would likely be O(N) as well. It would then be interpreting the third function's O(N^?), I would think O(N^2)